# .NET and reading xml file

Tags: .net, xml

I want to read following xml and populate **knowledge** tags in a combo box  ,**itemname** tag in a textbox and the rest in combo boxes as well.  Any code sample will be very helpful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<swobs>
    <item>
          <knowledge>1</knowledge>
          <knowledge>2</knowledge>
          <knowledge>3</knowledge>
          <knowledge>4</knowledge>
          <itemname>INS Gator Operator</itemname>
          <knowhow>1</knowhow>
          <knowhow>2</knowhow>
          <knowhow>3</knowhow>
          <knowhow>4</knowhow>
          <supervisor>1</supervisor>      
          <supervisor>2</supervisor>      
          <supervisor>3</supervisor>      
          <supervisor>4</supervisor>  
       </item>              
</swobs>
```

If I try this:

```
public void LoadXML() { 
    string myXMLfile = Server.MapPath("~/swobs.xml"); 
    DataSet dssowbs = new DataSet(); 
    try 
    { 
          dssowbs.ReadXml(myXMLfile); 
          DropDownList1.DataSource = dssowbs;
          DropDownList1.DataValueField = "knowledge"; 
          DropDownList1.DataBind(); 
     } 
     catch (Exception ex) 
     { 
          Response.Write(ex.ToString()); 
     } 
}
```

It throws an error.

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: Well what have you tried, and how far did you get?

Comment: If I try this ,

public void LoadXML()
        {
            string myXMLfile = Server.MapPath("~/swobs.xml");
            DataSet dssowbs = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                dssowbs.ReadXml(myXMLfile);
                DropDownList1.DataSource = dssowbs;
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "knowledge";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();             
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

It throws an error

Comment: Zeph: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn to love LINQ...  this is how easy it is:

```
private void LoadData()
        {
            var allData = XElement.Load("yourdatafile.xml");
            this.comboKnowledge.ItemsSource = allData.Descendants("knowledge").Select(x => x.Value);
            this.textItemName.Text = allData.Descendants("itemname").Select(x => x.Value).SingleOrDefault();
            this.comboKnowHow.ItemsSource = allData.Descendants("knowhow").Select(x => x.Value);
            this.comboSupervisor.ItemsSource = allData.Descendants("supervisor").Select(x => x.Value);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. Why does it shows an error on "ItemSource". I don;t see any such method for Combo.

Comment: You're right - I just took this example from a WPF application, but the same functionality would work just fine in ASP.NET, like so:

    `DropDownList1.DataSource = allData.Descendants("knowledge").Select(x => x.Value);
    DropDownList1.DataBind();`

Comment: Another option could be to use XmlDataSource, here is a very helpful link from Microsoft: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.xpath.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Matt working great..One more question, How to loop through entire xml in LINQ ?

Comment: The easiest way would be to do a `foreach` loop on a collection such as `allData.Element("item").Descendants()`.  This would allow you to loop over each node within the "item" tag.  Here is a reference to the XElement class from Microsoft - very helpful too: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx).

Comment: Hey Matt,if I have multiple <itemname> elements then it throws an error "Sequence contains more than one element" . Such case any property which helps to loop through and read all <itemname> tags ?